# intersection of two non empty subgroups of (Q,+) is not equal to {0}

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be a group of rationals under addition, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two non empty subgroups of G, then prove that $G_1 \cap G_2 \neq${0}

Comment: There are no *empty* subgroups. Perhaps you mean *nontrivial* instead?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a$ be a non-zero element of $G_1$ and $b$ be a non-zero element of $G_2$.

Let $a = \dfrac mn$ and $b = \dfrac pq$ where $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ are integers, and $n$ and $q$ are positive, and $m$ and $p$ are not zero.

We know that $npa = mp \in G_1$ and $mqb=mp \in G_2$.

Therefore, $mp$ is a common element in $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you mean non-trivial, not just non-empty.

Since we're considering $\mathbb{Q}$ as a group under addition, it, and all of its subgroups, are closed under integer multiplication. (This is reasonably obvious, but can be proved by induction if you want to be super precise.)

Let $0 \ne x \in G_1$ and $0 \ne y \in G_2$, and write $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{c}{d}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ all nonzero. Then $bx=a \in G_1$ and $dy=c \in G_2$, and so $ac \in G_1 \cap G_2$.